Unable to read/write HDD
Recently got a hand me down 3.5 inch Samsung hard drive(hd103sj). When I tried to open the drive using an HDD dock it opened the drive but I can't read or write anything. Windows explorer shows that it has 100% free space. It already has some data and I can go through the folder structure but cant open any files; cant even copy a file to my local drives. SMART attributes say it is of good health.
So far I have tried:

Format: write protected
Disk part: readonly attribute was no, but I still tried clear readonly attribute command.
EaseUS partion master: Tried this tool but it errored saying: Failed to disable write protection because the drive may have a physical problem.

I noticed that when the drive is plugged in, it starts up like a whirling noise is quite loud(maybe because its been a long time I heard that noise) and there is a fluttering/tapping noise. Maybe a mechanical issue? But if it was a mechanical issue would the drive allow me to go through it's existing folders?
Not much to lose here but thought i'll try and find out if there is anything I can try to salvage this drive.
Thank you

The drive is probably faulty but you shouldn't rule out the dock itself without further testing.

I tried other drives(both 2.5 and 3.5) so the dock works fine. From the folder names, it looks like the drive was used in some large company. Maybe the drive may have some kind of encryption due to this.

Given the sounds of your old disk you should consult with a recovery lab or as a last step connect it to a SATA slot that is connected directly to the mainboard. Use smartmontools to read out the SMART parameters and switch off your disk for further considerations.
Using a portable Linux should reduce stress that a Windows operating system automatically puts on your disk even when you are not accessing your disk. Smartmontools is cross-plattform and runs under linux as well.

Will need to try these, thank you.
